# Is there a way to get SWI prolog to never drop to an interactive prompt?

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to write a Prolog script and there are certain errors it can run into that cause the interpreter to drop to an interactive prompt. There is no possible situation in which that can be a good thing. How do I turn that off?

Edit: after some troubleshooting I've figured out that when Linux runs a script with the shebang operator it treats everything after the space as on single argument (???) which is why "-t halt" isn't working. Just passing -s won't stop it from dropping to the prompt.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command line option

`-t halt`

to immediately halt instead of returning to the toplevel.

Comment: For some reason when I do that from the command line it works but when I do that from the shebang at the top of the file it spews out the usage for swipl.